# Why is strcmp not working when I am reading a line from a file using malloc and determining the strings size independently

Tags: c, arrays, string

Alright, I am seriously puzzled.
I used a snippet of code that would open and read a file and store it in dynamic memory.  The output is executed in a void function, where the file is given line by line.  The size of the buffer character array was specified because the number of bytes that each line contains is unknown.  I want to compare the string that is read with a user input (given by char *word) to see if the program works or not.

In my mind, the strings can only be the same if both their sizes and their character sequences are equivalent, and the dynamic string size is not the same as the file's string size.  By using the counter in the main () loop (i.e. pos), I can determine the correct size of the string being read from the file and pass it on to the void function.  In the void handle_line function I copied in the characters from the buffer into char *temp because I know the number of characters that temp needs (i.e. pos) and can therefore initialize its size and copy the contents of the dynamic memory into the char *temp.  I proceeded to print out the bytes of the string sizes for line, temp, and word.  While char *temp and char *word gave their expected values, char *line was always four bytes.  Furthermore, the strcmp() did not give the expected result when H2O was read from the CompoundLib file--this in spite of the fact that I know that their sizes and character sequences are the same.
How can this be?  What am I missing???  Many thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void handle_line(char *line, int a) {
   char temp[a];
   int i=0;
   char temp_2[a];
   char *word="H2O";
   for(i=0;i<=a;i++)
       temp[i]=line[i];
   temp_2[i]=temp[i];
   printf("size of temp= %d\n",sizeof temp_2);
   printf("size of word= %d\n",sizeof word);
   printf("size of line= %d\n",sizeof line);
   if (strcmp(temp_2, word) == 0)
       puts("Strings equal");
   else
       puts("Strings do not equal");

   printf("%s\n", line);
   printf("%d\n", a);
   printf("%s\n",temp);

 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char c[1000];
    FILE *fptr;

    int size = 1024, pos;
    int c;
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(size);

    FILE *f = fopen("CompoundLib.txt", "r");
    if(f) {
        do { // read all lines in file
            pos = 0;
            do{ // read one line
               c = fgetc(f);


               if(c != EOF) buffer[pos++] = (char)c;
               if(pos >= size - 1) { // increase buffer length - leave room for 0
                    size *=2; //size = size*2

                }
            }while(c != EOF && c != '\n');

            buffer[pos] = 0;

            handle_line(buffer, pos);

        } while(c != EOF);
        fclose(f);
    }

    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems that you're not adding the NULL termination to the string.

Remember that c-strings are NULL-terminated, and you need the NULL char at the end so functions like strcmp can know the real size of the string.

And I can't see the braces in your for loop.

Comment: Your code won't compile. You have two variables having the same name in the same scope

Comment: `sizeof` operator, when applied to a pointer, always gives the size of a pointer, not the length of the string to which it points. It's "always four bytes" because that's how big pointers are on your system.

Comment: you increase the "size" variable, but you did not increase the size of the allocated memory

Comment: By putting your check for newline in the while part of the do/while, you are always including it in the string.

Comment: Did you forget to wrap `temp[i]=line[i];temp_2[i]=temp[i];` in `{ }` so that both of them would be in the body of the `for` loop?

Comment: Try running under a debugger, many of the mistakes identified here will be much more clear.

Comment: The correct format specifier for `size_t`(the type that `sizeof` returns) is `%zu`.

Comment: Also change `char temp[a];` and `char temp_2[a];` to `char temp[a+1];` and `char temp_2[a+1];` so that there is enough space for them to store the NUL-terminator as well.

Comment: I added the {} for the for loop; I put in the the memory check/update statements; and I found that increasing the value of int a by one was unnecessary as int pos corresponds to the string's length being read from the file with the null character.

My testing indicates that both temp's size and character sequence are correct but the strcmp(temp, word) does not confirm this as I would expect.

Comment: Les - I have my debugger running, and you are correct; \n is being copied and passed into the void function.  I don't suppose that there is a method to transform \n into \0 in the void function?  I'm working on it, but if you have any ideas I would be happy to hear them.